# Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

i am getting an error when i press my cmdbutton,
When i debug it it highlights arr(nr, i) = arr(r, i)

[image]

this is my code

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim r%, nr%, arr, lr&, i%
arr = Worksheets("DROP").Range("L4:T100")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(r, 1) <> "" Then
            nr = nr + 1
            For i = 1 To 12
                arr(nr, i) = arr(r, i)
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
    
    With Sheets("MASTER")
        lr = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("B" & lr & ":" & "J" & lr).Resize(nr) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Also where would i add in Range(B4:J100).clear so after the code runs and copys the right side onto my master sheet, it then clears the left side ready for the next extract to be dropped in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Values If Column Not Blank

- The error is occurring because your ranges have 9 columns yet you are trying to loop through 12. Instead of 12, use 9 or `UBound(arr, 2)`.
- Here is how I would do it.

**Append**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "DROP"
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "L4:T100"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "MASTER"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "B"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim sr As Long, c As Long, dr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If Len(CStr(Data(sr, 1))) > 0 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, DST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = Data
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Overwrite (Always the same range)**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "DROP"
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "L4:T100"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "MASTER"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "B4"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim sr As Long, c As Long, dr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To rCount
        If Len(CStr(Data(sr, 1))) > 0 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    For dr = dr To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Data(dr, c) = Empty
        Next c
    Next dr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = Data
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: ahh ye ok i see, thanks heaps mate